# Reactjs post form data to external payment page URL

Tags: reactjs, form-data, form-post, external-url

Hi anybody know how to post reactjs form data to external URL like this.

```
<form id="fc_checkout" action="https://checkout.freecharge.in/api/v1/co/oauth/wallet/add" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="callbackUrl" value='somevalue' />
<input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value='somevalue' />
<input type="hidden" name="checksum" value='somevalue' />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value='somevalue' />
<input type="hidden" name="loginToken" value='somevalue' />
<input type="hidden" name="channel" value='somevalue' />
<input type="hidden" name="metadata" value='somevalue' />
</form>



Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: try something first. you wont get help without effort.

Comment: Plenty of tutorials out there. ex: https://blog.stvmlbrn.com/2017/04/07/submitting-form-data-with-react.html

Comment: my question is to post the data to external url with redirection

Comment: document.getElementById("form_id").submit(); have you tried this?